# Ubuntu 20.04 (WSL1) 上に VirtualBoxをインストールしたい

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, wsl

**VirtualBoxをインストール**

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install virtualbox -y
```

上の2つのコマンドを実行し､

`vboxmanage --version` でバージョンを確認すると､下記のエラー文が表示されたので､`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms` を実行したのですが、エラー文は変わらずVirtualBoxも実行できません｡

**エラー文**

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-Microsoft.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
6.1.38_Ubuntur153438
```

Comment: 何を実行しようとしてるか不明ですが, WSL1は Linux APIを**ほとんど**実行できるけどすべてではありません。WSL2はエミュレーションなので実行できる可能性高いけどエミュレーションのエミュレーションでは遅くなるでしょう。Linuxで VirtualBox動かすなら実機が望ましいかも

Comment: エラーを解決する方法はありますか？

Comment: "character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist" に関しては, この質問が役に立つかも？ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350358/how-do-i-resolve-the-character-device-dev-vboxdrv-does-not-exist-error-in-ubu